# Would using a QWERTY keyboard with DVORAK output cause keylogger to log DVORAK?

Tags: malware, keyloggers, encoding

I have QWERT keyboard, but I have set the keyboard settings in Windows to DVORAK. So if I type "test" it comes out as "y.oy". Would the key logger log "test" or "y.oy" in its records?

Comment: It really depends if the logger is designed to hardware-read the input or consider things like regional settings.

Comment: @Overmind I had a software keylogger in mind.

Comment: The  software key-logger can be designed both ways: it can ignore or not the regional and KB settings.

Comment: Which is more likely (direct, with regional): 40/50, 50/50, 60/40 ?

Comment: I've put that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring the direct hardware reading (via driver privileges), a software key-logger can be designed both ways: it can ignore or not the regional and KB settings.

It's more likely (about 4:1) that a software will consider the current regional settings in all aspects related to that. Statistically, that's what I determined. I do prefer to ignore those settings, but most programs (including many banking ones) don't. Apparently It's easier to read and use the regional settings.

Answer (score 6):

## Ultimately ... It wouldn't matter

at best this key substitution would equiv to a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) ... which can be [easily broken](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/127993/92213).

Qwerty

> The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog

Dvorak

> Yd. 'gcjt xpr,b urq hgml.e rk.p yd. na;f eri

[online translator](https://chaidarun.com/dvorak)

Comment: I think it's a Simple Substitution cipher rather than a Caesar cipher. Caesar cipher is a +/- positional shift that is the same for every letter. QWERTY > DVORAK is more akin to a per-character substitution cipher where each character on the keyboard has a 1 to 1 replacement with another key.